# Order by date when a format 'dd-MM-YYYY' is given in the select statement is not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I store the date in a `DATETIME` field in my database. When I create a select statement I need to show it with format `'%d-%m-%Y'` but I have problems sorting the data by date.

this is my selec statement:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS Date
FROM Purchase
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-06-30' ORDER BY Date asc;
```

But the data does not get sorted by date. How can I solve this?

Comment: Use a different alias, or qualify the `Date` in the order by with the table name, so MySQL knows you want to use the field value, not the value of the select expression.

Comment: Visualization of your date should not be done by MySQL. It's the task for your frontend UI (e.g. web page). You will be better off if you keep date in it's native format - and it's easier to store it in your program datetime objects.

Comment: Without an ordering clause, there is no guarantee of result order. Even if it was sorted on your result, by happenstance, it would sort as a string so the 11th would come before the 2nd...

Comment: @mgrollins that is exactly the problem I have.

Comment: OK @Roly, then the answer below should work well for you. As a general practice I try to use alias names that are different from any existing field names in the query to keep things explicit.

Comment: Store dates in MySQL's format.  That would have avoided all this hassle.

Comment: @RickJames That's exactly what I ended up doing, as suggested by @mvp; even though the accepted answer works at first, I had to do what you are saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the same name for the column date and formatted  date then the order by work for the alias column  .. so is order by day, month, year as in your format  ('%d-%m-%Y')

then try changing the alias  name

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS My_Date
FROM Purchase
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-06-30' 
ORDER BY Date asc;
```

or use a proper order  by format

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%d-%m-%Y')Date
FROM Purchase
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-06-30' 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%Y-%m-%d') asc;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by telling SQL to order by the `Purchase.Date` field instead of the formatted string date value.  When you chose to order by "Date" with no table or table alias specified, SQL assumes you want the formatted result aliased as Date, not the "Date" field from your Purchase table.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS My_Date
FROM Purchase
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-06-30' 
ORDER BY Purchase.Date asc;
```